# Can't make Cuda with pyTorch

Tags: pytorch, visual-studio-2022

I cannot make cuda run when with torch.

Im using this:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')  
                model = model.to(device)
```

I have installed:

```
torch 2.0.1
VS 2022 17.4.0
Cuda 11.8.0
win 11
```

and use it with:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
```

what else am I missing ... why doesn't ir run?

I installed other vs and other cuda ... but now I have currently those and cuda path is added

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! I suspect that you need to install a version of `pytorch` that contains the CUDA binaries, by default `pip install torch` installs a CPU version of `pytorch`.

First, uninstall pytorch: `pip uninstall torch`

You can go to the following page to find the right installation command for your platform: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Comment: I need the GPU v. ...  Also, do I install pyTorch or torch?

Comment: @myenlightendgod Small typo, meant to say `pip uninstall torch`, edited my answer to match. Torch is the name of the original implementation written in Lua, Pytorch is the name of the project that adapted this library to Python, but under pypi it's listed as `torch`.

Comment: sorry ... I have to uncheck coz I still cant make it work

Comment: @myenlightendgod That's okay, sorry you couldn't get it to work.

Comment: don't you know any else I could do to make the gpu work? could I be doing something else wrong? does the v of msvs make any difference? what are u using? I've installed it with pip ... but I use conda ... I will reinstallit with conda ... and if it works I will check your response.

Comment: What installation command did you end up running from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/? I'm not at home so I can't check my graphics card, but your card should be compatible with CUDA. Have you tried updating your card's drivers?

Comment: drivers are updated, I have nvidia gforce experience ...